# XSL how to calculate how deep a node is

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking to calculate how deep the current node is. below is an example of the xml code and the output I want to have

```
<boxes>  
    <box name="box A">  
        <box name="box B">  
        </box>  
    </box>  
    <box name="box C">  
        <box name="box D">  
            <box name="box E">  
                <box name="box F">  
                </box>  
            </box>  
        </box>  
    </box>  
</boxes>
```

XSL would look like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="box">  
    <xsl:value-of select="DEPTH"/><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>  
    <xsl:for-each select="box">
        <xsl:value-of select="DEPTH"/><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>  
        <xsl:for-each select="box">  
            <xsl:value-of select="DEPTH"/><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>  
            <xsl:for-each select="box">
                <xsl:value-of select="DEPTH"/><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>  
                <xsl:for-each select="box">  
                    <xsl:value-of select="DEPTH"/><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>  
                </xsl:for-each>  
            </xsl:for-each>  
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output would look like this
1 box A
2 box B
1 box C
2 box D
3 box E
4 box F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking to calculate how deep the current node is.

Try:

```
count(ancestor-or-self::*)
```

(assuming "node" means "element" in this context).

---

For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="box">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor-or-self::*)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will return:

```
2   box A
3   box B
2   box C
3   box D
4   box E
5   box F
```

Comment: That is the answer I already found in another forum post but for some reason when I use it I get the same number for each node. It should change of course. When I say node, I mean "box" in this case.

Comment: I have added an example of how to use it. In this example, the level is calculated overall. If you want it to start counting at some predefined level, you need to specify this somehow - for example, use `count(ancestor-or-self::box)` to count only a `box` as a level.

Comment: Thank you. I must have some error in my code because it returns the same number over and over and in your example it seems to change like needed.

Comment: The only thing that was different about my actual code is that my match was actually matching an ascendant node/element and the Box node/element was being tested in an If. i changed it to a for-each and now it works like your original answer. When I simplified it for this post I ended up discovering why I was not getting the answer I would have seen with your answer. thanks again for the help on this.